# Maven: Problem with mave-assemby-plugin: it's trying to process a virtual second assembly.xml not existing in project

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

When executing mvn asembly:single it works fine (generate the desired file) but fails at end… If I execute with -X this is the output:

```
    ...
    [INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: ../assembly.xml
    [DEBUG] Field directory source: ${project.build.directory} interpolated to: target
    [DEBUG] After assembly is interpolated:
    
            <?xml version="1.0"?>
            <assembly xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
              <id>bin</id>
              <formats>
                <format>tar.gz</format>
              </formats>
              <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                  <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
                  <includes>
                    <include>*</include>
                  </includes>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>objs</exclude>
                    <exclude>archive-tmp</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.o</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/*.gz</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                  <directory>target</directory>
                </fileSet>
              </fileSets>
            </assembly>
        
        **( SINCE HERE ALL IS OK!)**
        
        [DEBUG] Field directory source: ${project.basedir} interpolated to: .
        [DEBUG] Field directory source: ${project.build.directory} interpolated to: target
        [DEBUG] Field directory source: ${project.build.directory}/site interpolated to: target/site
        [DEBUG] After assembly is interpolated:
        
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <assembly xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.1.0"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <id>bin</id>
          <formats>
            <format>tar.gz</format>
            <format>tar.bz2</format>
            <format>zip</format>
          </formats>
          <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
              <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
              <includes>
                <include>README*</include>
                <include>LICENSE*</include>
                <include>NOTICE*</include>
              </includes>
              <directory>.</directory>
            </fileSet>
            <fileSet>
              <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
              <includes>
                <include>*.jar</include>
              </includes>
              <directory>target</directory>
            </fileSet>
            <fileSet>
              <outputDirectory>docs</outputDirectory>
              <directory>target/site</directory>
            </fileSet>
          </fileSets>
        </assembly>
    
    (**Where the hell does he get this second XML from???)**
    
    [WARNING] The assembly id bin is used more than once.
    [DEBUG] All known ContainerDescriptorHandler components: [plexus, metaInf-spring, file-aggregator, metaInf-services]
    [DEBUG] FileSet[] dir perms: -1 file perms: -1
    [DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
    [DEBUG] NOT reformatting any files in F:\Desarrollo\MAVENIZADO\Log\target
    [DEBUG] Adding file-set in: ... to archive location: .../
    [DEBUG] Adding exclude for assembly working-directory: assembly/work
    File-Set source directory: .../target
    [INFO] Building **tar: xxxxxxxx\target\xxxx-1.0-bin.tar.gz** **<-- THIS IS THE WANTED FILE AND IT'S OK!!!**
    
    **NOW IT'S PROCESSING THE FILESETS OF THE OTHER XML invented by himself!!!! :**
    
    [DEBUG] All known ContainerDescriptorHandler components: [plexus, metaInf-spring, file-aggregator, metaInf-services]
    [DEBUG] FileSet[] dir perms: -1 file perms: -1
    [DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
    [DEBUG] NOT reformatting any files in ...
    [DEBUG] Adding file-set in: ...0/
    [DEBUG] FileSet[] dir perms: -1 file perms: -1
    [DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
    [DEBUG] NOT reformatting any files in ...target
    [DEBUG] Adding file-set in: F:\Desarrollo\MAVENIZADO\Log\target to archive location: ...
    [DEBUG] Adding exclude for assembly working-directory: assembly/work
    File-Set source directory: ....target
    [DEBUG] FileSet[docs/] dir perms: -1 file perms: -1
    [DEBUG] The archive base directory is 'null'
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time:  2.046 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2021-07-26T11:36:22+02:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.3.0:single (default-cli) on project Log: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bin: archive cannot be empty -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.3.0:single (default-cli) on project Log: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bin: archive cannot be empty
```

IT FAILS DOING SOMETHING THAT IS NOT WHAT IS ASKED...
THE FILE I WANT IS CORRETLY GENERATED.

Comment: First please format your post correct...second add the pom files and your structure of your project...

Comment: Why the plugin adds a second "invented" assemby.xml?

Comment: Without the information @khmarbaise asked for, we can't tell.

Comment: It's irrelevant. This behaviour occurs ever. The plugin wants  a forced structure with /site folder and README.txt, INSTALL.txt  and NOTICE.txt.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin is using a default assembly definition named "bin" (why they do this if nobody wants this invented defenition??? ). SOLUTION: Don't use "bin" id in assenbly and don't refer to a assembly called "bin" (`<descriptorRef>bin</descriptorRef>`) in pom.xml. "bin" is for creator's only!